# How to generate TimeUUID in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, timeuuid

Does anyone know how to generate TimeBased UUIDs in Java/Scala?

Here is the column family:

```
CREATE table col(ts timeuuid)
```

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.4

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cassandra has UUIDGen for generating Timeuuids. The source for this is here:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java

Answer (score 17):

If you are using the Datastax drivers you can use the utility class, [UUIDs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html), to generate one

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;
....
UUID timeBasedUuid = UUIDs.timeBased();
```

Answer (score 4):

i am using the same way for cassandra cli, and for column name i am using

```
System.currentTimeMillis().toString
```

---

```
scala>     val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis().toString
timestamp: String = 1406279679674
```

**UPDATE**

mainly it depends on your row key if rowKey is your `userId` or something, then there is no chance of submission of duplicate record in miliseconds but if you think it can be repeat then use

```
val timestamp = com.eaio.uuid.UUIDGen.newTime().toString
```

Answer (score 1):

this is work for cassandra 4.x version

first, import libary in `build.sbt`

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datastax.oss" % "java-driver-core" % "4.15.0"
)
```

example

```scala
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids

import java.time.ZonedDateTime

object Test extends App {
  val timeText = "2022-01-01T00:01:01.002345Z"
  val datetime = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeText)
  val uuid = Uuids.endOf(datetime.toInstant.toEpochMilli)
  println(uuid) // e79b51af-6a95-11ec-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f
}
```

test on cassandra

```
cqlsh:test> create table aaa (id timeuuid primary key, t text);

cqlsh:test> insert into aaa(id,t) values(e79b51af-6a95-11ec-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f, 't4');

cqlsh:test> select toTimestamp(id), t from aaa;

 system.totimestamp(id)          | t
---------------------------------+----
 2022-01-01 00:01:01.002000+0000 | t4
```